# Git creates problems in cmd for other programs

Tags: git, environment-variables

Programs I have installed:

- Apache Ant
- Android SDK
- Node
- Git

When I install Git I am unable to access "android" and "ant" from cmd. As soon as I uninstall Git I am able to access them.

I selected the first option when installing Git which is the safest but still same problem.

I have have set the path correctly in environment variable for all the 4 tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git Bash was creating the problem. Now I have reinstalled Git with "git-cheetah shell extension" and all seems to work fine.